# Need to remove last string

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have code

```
echo whoisdatacenter.com_101_llc.csv | sed 's/_/ /g' | perl -pe 's/\w+/\L\u$&/g'
```

It gives me

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Whoisdatacenter.Com 101 Llc.Csv
```

How can I achieve

```
WHOISDATACENTER.COM 101 LLC
```

(in caps and ".csv" removed)

An answer with a little bit of explanation will be very helpful ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed for `\U`:

```
$ echo 'whoisdatacenter.com_101_llc.csv' |
    sed 's/\.csv$//; s/_/ /g; s/.*/\U&/g'
WHOISDATACENTER.COM 101 LLC
```

Comment: You should add domain names like `foo.csv.com` to your sample input/output as you're getting several answers that'll work for exactly the domain name you provided but won't work for others.

Comment: here s/\.csv$//

$ represent end of my line of text?

Comment: Correct. The `$` represents the end of the line so that if `.csv` just happened to also appear in the middle of the line it wouldnt be removed.

Comment: I am getting predefine values... these are basically not domains.. some companies name like aegean_domains_llc.csv.

Comment: so when i add your code in this echo 'aegean_domains_llc.csv' |     sed 's/\.csv$//; s/_/ /g; s/.*/\U&/g'
AEGEAN DOMAINS LLC
it work well

Comment: Right, it'll work for any input. no matter how many `.`s or `.csv`s appear in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo whoisdatacenter.com_101_llc.csv | awk -F ".csv" '{print toupper($1)}'
```

We set the field separator as `.csv`, so that field `$1` is always the substring up to the first `.csv` occurrence (in the present case, `whoisdatacenter.com_101_llc`). Then, string function `toupper` is used on that field, converting it to uppercase characters.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for why this solves the problem?

Comment: @economy Sure, sorry I usually do that but this time I forgot it!

Answer (score 0):

`\L\u` (uppercase the first, lowercase the rest) should be `\U` (uppercase all).

```
perl -pe's/_/ /g; s/\.csv$//; s/.*/\U$&/'
```

You could also use

```
perl -pe's/_/ /g; s/\.csv$//; $_ = uc($_)'

perl -pe'$_ = uc(s/_/ /gr =~ s/\.csv$//r)'

perl -ne'print uc(s/_/ /gr =~ s/\.csv$//r)'
```

You'll have to fix your locale to get rid of the warning —something you should do no matter what— but it shouldn't stop any of the above from working.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using sed and tr commands combination.

```
echo whoisdatacenter.com_101_llc.csv|sed 's!.csv! !g; s!_! !g'|tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

> WHOISDATACENTER.COM 101 LLC

First sed command replace .csv file with empty.

Second sed command replace special character(_) with empty.

Using tr command converting lower case letters to upper case letters